# HTML Editor With iFrame Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.grid {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 50px;

}

.container {
    background: #e3e3e3;
}


textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

iframe {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: aqua;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<hmtl>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
       <script>
            (function() {
$('grid').height($(window).height() );

var frame = $('iframe');
var contents = frame.contents();
var body = contents.find('body')
var styleTag = contents.find('head').append('<style></style>').children('style');

$('textarea').focus(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.keyup(function() {
if ($this.attr('id') == 'html') {
body.html($this.val() );
}
else
{
styleTag.text($this.val() );
}
});
});
});
            
</script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class = "container grid">
            <form>
                <h2>HTML</h2>
                <textarea id = "html"></textarea>
                
                <h2>CSS</h2>
                <textarea id = "css"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <div class = "output grid">
            <iframe></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</hmtl>
```

I'm trying to make a simple online html editor (like codepen) and, the result is not showing up. I have tried to solve this problem for more than an hour! Please Help! This problem is bugging me, and the internet won't help! I'm suspecting the jQuery has issues, but it doesn't seem like it

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific than "the result is not showing up".

Comment: I want a user to type a html code in the html and css textarea and have it "displayed" in the iFrame. So far when typing html and css code in the textarea, the iFrame doesn't seem to respond to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your script is in your head tags instead of the closing body tag. Meaning the script is run before any content is added.

If you're intension is to keep the script in your head tag you will need to put your function inside of a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // your script
})
```

The JQuery equivalent...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your script
})
```

[and that's all you need to get your editor working.](http://jsbin.com/xevidixuto/edit?html,output)

If you want to integrate an advanced code editor with an extensive API I recommend looking into [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) or the [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/).

I developed [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#b6b39c95ec91f42950957a1ac8dc707f) and I use it on my tablet both online and offline. It has a few demos such as a Code Editor (CodeMirror), a splitter (from [jqxSplitter](http://jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxsplitter/index.htm#demos/jqxsplitter/defaultfunctionality.htm) and more.

These are just some additional tips to help you get started making your code playground.

I also made a video if you want to understand more about [how to make your own coding playground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUnWRuTI4Vo).

Comment: I already made the changes, but can't get the Javascript / jQuery to work :/ I already checked your JS Bin and the code JS code are the same and the HTML. I also copied your JS Bin code into my index.html and tried running it. No succes. Yet your JS Bin example worked. My example is at obertguo.github.io/tryittest . I have copied the code with no success at all.

Comment: As I said, replace `(function() {` with `$(document).ready(function() {` right after your opening script tag.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasted your time when the answer was  right in front of me. I just foolishly didn't do what you said. Thank you :)